# Image in a tableView gets bigger during swipe left to delete

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview

hello I when I do swipe left in tableView, the image gets bigger and push to the second row. here is the image for better understanding
[image]

The image is pushing to the second row.How can I fix this.

Comment: Try setting `clipsToBounds` to `true` on the image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `clipsToBounds = true` on the image view of the cell and that should do it - it looks like the image is simply displaying its content outside of its bounds.

Comment: What I don't understand is why Clips to Bounds is not the default for an image view. I regard this as a bug.

Comment: @matt It's only a bug if it's not intended, right? For some god-awful reason this is the default for all UIViews...

Comment: When would you _ever_ want an image view not to clip to bounds? The whole notion makes no sense. If you drag an image into the canvas from the Media Library, it becomes an image view that _does_ clip to bounds. Why? Because that's what makes sense. Yet if you drag a "bare" image view from the Object library, it doesn't clip to bounds. And this, as Stack Overflow clearly shows, keeps catching people. If it has no "purpose" but to trap people, it's a bug in my view.